# How to store text file contents into an arrays and display them

Tags: java, arrays, readfile

I am trying to store the content of my text file into an arrays and display them in the console. I also want to find the empty space in the file and insert a game board there which I designed earlier.

Here is my text file content:

```
rfhrf
1
4

sdtgv
1
1

rfhrf
1
3

sdtgv
2
1

rfhrf
4
4

sdtgv
3
1
```

and here is what I have so far:

```java
File text = new File("actions.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println(line);   
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

any help would be great.

Comment: How do you want to divide it? word per index? letter per index? Please be more specific

Comment: the game board would be a tik tak toe board, the integer numbers represent the row and col, i need the integer values to be stored in array so that i can put them on the game board.

Comment: What do you want to store at Array? Words or Words Counts?

Comment: I want to store each line of the text file in an array (Words), find the empty line and insert my game board in there which i designed earlier.

Comment: Could you accept my answer if it solved your problem? Or maybe explain why it didn't so I can adapt.

Comment: Unfortunately your answer didnt work for me, I agree with Chris , i would probably dont need an array. some how i am unable to use the two integer numbers printed to the console(row, col) and place them in the game board without user input, so it looks like an action replay

Comment: @user2215240 My answer solved your problem? Or I will edit my answer according to what you need.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is define a format by convention, alterating your file, to make it look like this:

```
rfhrf;1;4
sdtgv;1;1
...
```

and then for every read line, you can see the value and the position. Example:

```
File text = new File("actions.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {

        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        String params = line.split(";");
        String value = params[0];
        int row = Integer.parseInt(params[1]);
        int col = Integer.parseInt(params[2]);

        myArray[row][col] = value;

    }

    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That should help you, if I actually understood what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to use Array. Just try the following! Hope it works!

```
File text = new File("actions.txt");
try {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(text);

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("This is Space!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(line);
        } 
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }

    scanner.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do your own class that provides all your needs(like space counts,words) let's say MyClassContainer and then put all your MyClassContainer in a hashtable.It is quick and easy